# Python grayscaling rgb image with percentage

Tags: python, css, opencv, python-imaging-library, grayscale

I can find many codes that help to convert RGB image to a grayscale image.
But none of them shows me how to grayscaling with adjustable percentage like CSS supports.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/grayscale

```
img {
  filter: grayscale(25%);
}
```

Could you please guide me to build a function in python to return a grayscale image in rgb mode:

```
rgb_image = rgb_to_gray(rgb_img, percent = 0.25)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Convert the image fully to grayscale. Then blend the original with the grayscale by the 0.75 original and 0.25 grayscale using cv2.addWeighted(). See https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gafafb2513349db3bcff51f54ee5592a19

Comment: Note: the grayscale image will need to be converted to 3 equal channels using `cv2.merge([grayscale,grayscale,grayscale])` or `cv2.cvtColor(grayscale, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)` before using in cv2.addWeighted

Answer (score 1):

The idea provided by @fmw42 is the best way. However, you cannot use the grayscaled image as is in the function `cv2.addWeighted()`. Both the images used within the function must of the same dimensions. Since a grayscale converted image is of single dimension, it will throw an error `Sizes of input arguments do not match`.

So first lets create a possible grayscale image in three dimensions, it can be done as follows:

```
img = cv2.imread(image_path)

# split the image into three channels
b,g,r = cv2.split(img) 

# Formula for converting to grayscale single channel
#0.2989 * R + 0.5870 * G + 0.1140 * B 

r= 0.2989 * r 
g = 0.5870 * g 
b = 0.1140 * b 

res = b+g+r
# grayscale single channel image
res = res.astype(np.uint8)

# to obtain 3-channel grayscale image repeat res across 3 channels
gray = cv2.merge((res, res, res))
```

Now as mentioned we use `cv2.addWeighted()` function as follows:

```
# the percentage of gray ranges from 0 to 1.0
for i in np.arange(0.0, 1.1, 0.1):
    modified_img = cv2.addWeighted(gray, i, img, 1.0-i, 0)
    cv2.imshow('Toned image', modified_img)
```

**Results**

Percentage: 0

[image]

Percentage: 30

[image]

Percentage: 70

[image]

Percentage :100

[image]

Comment: Why not just convert to grayscale. No need to do that in multiple steps?  `cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`

Comment: @fmw42 It won't work. Since `cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)` returns grayscale image of single dimension. Whereas, `cv2.addWeighted()` requires both the images to be of equal dimensions

Comment: Yes, but I meant that you do not have to create the grayscale image by formula and all the extra work you do. You can convert to grayscale, then merge 3 copies to make 3 channel.

Comment: @fmw42 I got your point.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do that in Python/OpenCV. This example is 75% gray (and 25% original).

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread("firefox.jpg")

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# make gray into 3 channels
gray = cv2.cvtColor(gray, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

# blend gray with original
result = cv2.addWeighted(gray, 0.75, img, 0.25, 0)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('firefox_75pct_gray.jpg',result)

# show results
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]